# Finite subgroups of $\text{PGL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Let $p$ be a prime number and $n\ge 1$ an integer. Call $N:=p^n-1$.

> Can the cyclic group of order $N$ be contained in $\text{GL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$? Can it be contained in $\text{PGL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$?

What can be said if $\mathbf{Z}$ is replaced by the ring of integers of a number field? For example a cyclotomic field generated by a primitive $m$-th root of unity.

The question originated from the reading of a [paper](https://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-pierre-serre/UPL3821667391778701726_6___Bounds_for_the_orders.pdf) of Serre, building on Minkowski's results on finite subgroups of $\text{GL}_N(\mathbf{Q})$. Namely, I was trying to see if the condition that the cyclic group of order one less than a prime power ($N=p^n-1$ as in the body of the question) is contained in $\text{PGL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$ or $\text{GL}_N(\mathbf{Z})$, puts any constraints on $p$ or on $n$. For instance, whether if $p$ is large, $n$ is forced to be one.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \dots \\
 & & \dots & & \\
 & &  \dots & 0  & 1 \\
1 & 0 & \dots  & \end{pmatrix}$$
i.e. 1's on the superdiagonal and 1 in the bottom left corner. It corresponds to the permutation $(1\, 2\, 3 \,\dots \, N)$ of the basis vectors. If $N$ is odd, it even has determinant 1, otherwise determinant $-1$. And of course, it has order $N$, thus generating a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/N\Bbb{Z}$. This naturally works for any $N$.

Any matrix contained in $GL_N(\Bbb{Z})$ is also "contained" in $PGL_N(\Bbb{Z})$, since the former surjects onto the latter.

Comment: The fact that $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{Z})$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $N$ does not immediately imply that $\mathrm{PGL}_N(\mathbb{Z})$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $N$, since the order of this subgroup could decrease in the quotient. For example, the matrix $(-1)I$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $2$ in $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{Z})$, but its image in $\mathrm{PGL}_N(\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial. However, all you need to do to finish the argument is to observe that none of the permutation matrices in your group are in the center (the kernel of the quotient map).

Comment: That's true, I should have mentioned that. But naturally, as you say, my example will work in both cases.